# AWS Metrics Filter pattern Extraction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have awsService.log logs being sent to CloudWatch and I want to create a metric filter to extract the error value.

Example:

`06/13/2020 07:35:33 : 578 : 3 : error occurs`

`05/13/2020 07:35:33 : 3 : 3 : error occurs`

The error value I would like to extract is : `3`

I tried with many regrex expressions like `* : * : 3 :` but it doesnot work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no complex patterning (such as Regex) is currently supported with Metric Filters.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) you have 3 choices

- Trying to match based on an exact string (`[": 3 :"]`)
- Using JSON metric filters (not possible for your example as it requires JSON)
- Filtering based on condition of this being a space separated event (`[date, time, seperator1, int1, seperator2, int2=3, ...]`)

Regarding extracting the error value, Metrics Filters provide a count for every time this event occurs, they don't count values from the query itself.